# Select query within select query

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT
  merchant.merchantname 'MerchantName',
  COUNT(transaction.transactionid) 'NoofTransaction',
  SUM(transactionamount) 'TotalAmount'
    (SELECT statement.statementbalance from statement where transactionid = statement.transactionid ORDER BY merchantid LIMIT 1) AS 'BalanceRemaining'
  FROM transaction
  RIGHT JOIN merchant ON transaction.merchantid = merchant.merchantid
    RIGHT JOIN statement ON transaction.transactionid = statement.transactionid
  WHERE transaction.transactiondate = '2018-01-15'
  GROUP BY merchant.merchantid;
    ORDER BY merchant.merchantid ASC;
```

Im trying to select a query within a select query which allows me to select the last inserted result of Balance Remaining.

Comment: What does the error say

Comment: which table does "Balance Remaining" come from? Is it `statement`? What is the actual column name? what is/are the column/s that determine "last inserted" result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the following revised query for your requirement which does not join to the statement table as such a join will probably multiply the number of rows and therefore produce errors in the results.

```
SELECT
      merchant.merchantname  'MerchantName'
    , COUNT(t.transactionid) 'NoofTransaction'
    , SUM(t.transactionamount) 'TotalAmount'
    , (
            SELECT
                  statement.statementbalance
            FROM statement
            WHERE t.transactionid = statement.transactionid
            ORDER BY
                  some_date_column DESC LIMIT 1 
      )                      
      AS 'BalanceRemaining'
FROM merchant
INNER JOIN `transaction` t ON merchant.merchantid = t.merchantid
WHERE t.transactiondate = '2018-01-15'
GROUP BY
      merchant.merchantid
ORDER BY
      merchant.merchantid ASC
;
```

NOTE, that the date column(s) to use for ordering ("last inserted") isn't given in the question.

Also I have reversed the table relationship. There isn't much point in using right joins in my view as it is almost always easier to structure the query to use the "from table" so that subsequent joins never need a right join. In this particular case an outer join of any form does not appear to be needed due to the where clause, so an inner join is used instead.

**added**: To list all merchants:

```
SELECT
      merchant.merchantname  'MerchantName'
    , COUNT(t.transactionid) 'NoofTransaction'
    , SUM(t.transactionamount) 'TotalAmount'
    , (
            SELECT
                  statement.statementbalance
            FROM statement
            WHERE t.transactionid = statement.transactionid
            ORDER BY
                  some_date_column DESC LIMIT 1 
      )                      
      AS 'BalanceRemaining'
FROM merchant
LEFT JOIN `transaction` t ON merchant.merchantid = t.merchantid
                         AND t.transactiondate = '2018-01-15'
GROUP BY
      merchant.merchantid
ORDER BY
      merchant.merchantid ASC
;
```

Comment: thanks. this is exactly what i was looking for. Is there a way to add in all the rows of a table within this query. Say, the merchant.merchantname?

Comment: If you need every merchant in the result even if there is no matching transactions then use a `LEFT JOIN` to the transactions table also need to change the where clause. by the way `transaction` is a reserved word in some databases so I recommend you always use backticks when referring to that table.

Comment: see **added** query variant

Comment: Thanks. It works. Last question (honest), im having tough time with including the last remaining statementbalance of statement even if there are no transactions on current day and viewing all the merchants. How would that be corrected in the sql query?